Azure Web App timeout issue with Telegram bot deployed
I have a Telegram bot built with Python, Pyrogram, and deployed on an Azure Web App. Initially, the bot worked fine, but after some time, it stopped responding. The Azure Web App failed to start within the expected time limit (website_container_start_time_limit).
The logs showed that the Gunicorn server (running the Flask app) started successfully but encountered timeout errors and terminated the worker process after around 10 minutes. This cycle repeated until the Azure Web App timed out after 30 minutes, indicating the app wasn't responding to HTTP requests within the configured time limit.
Surprisingly, around 30 minutes after encountering timeouts, the bot started working again without any changes to the code or configuration.
Logs:-
2024-05-21T17:07:43.804Z ERROR - Container telegram-bot for site telegram-bot did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 1819.1139457 sec


2024-05-21T17:07:43.838Z ERROR - Container telegram-bot-dignified-india_0_d3110031 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

I tried redeploying the bot to see if that would resolve the issue, but it didn't work. I also added environment variables in the Application Settings:
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800
WEBSITES_PORT=8080
I expected that by increasing the WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT value and specifying the WEBSITES_PORT, the bot would have enough time to start up and handle incoming requests without timing out.
Reference Code
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("abc_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)

#Define a function to handle the /start command
@app.on_message(filters.command("start"))
def start_command(client, message):
    #Send "Hello" as a response to the /start command
    message.reply_text("Hello!")

#Run the bot
app.run()


Despite incorporating the startup command, the system encountered worker timeout errors and SIGKILL signals. The logs indicate that the application service attempted to pull and download various file system layers, but eventually at the end container failed to start within the expected time limit, resulting in container restart errors.
want to mention that i do not have anything related to flask in my code its just a pyrogram code
also want to mention the bot works for sometime and stops working after the container error.

Also wanted to ask what all things are required to add in the webapp setting, apart from
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800,WEBSITES_PORT=8080, BOT_TOKEN and  startup command

I tried the sample code below to send messages to the Telegram bot and deployed it to the Azure app service through containers without any issues.
I faced the same timeout error because the Telegram bot token expired after some time. So, I created a new Telegram bot and used the new bot token.
Code :
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Received /start command from user {update.effective_user.id}")
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your bot. How can I help you?')

async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Received /help command from user {update.effective_user.id}")
    await update.message.reply_text('Help!')

async def echo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Received a message from user {update.effective_user.id}: {update.message.text}")
    await update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def main():
    BOT_TOKEN = '<bot_token>'
    if not BOT_TOKEN:
        logger.error("Bot token not found. Please set the BOT_TOKEN environment variable.")
        return

    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))

    application.add_error_handler(lambda update, context: logger.error(f"Update {update} caused error {context.error}"))
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Telegram bot Output :

Local output :

Docker Image local output:

Then, I pushed my image to the Azure container registry as shown below.

After creating a web app with the Container registry, I added the BOT_TOKEN to the web app's Environment variables as shown below.
BOT_TOKEN = <bot_token>


Azure web app Telegram bot output :

Azure web app Log stream :


IF possible, can you do it using pyrogram library, i have made a whole project in it!

@YeshpalSingh The main issue for the time out is the token expiration, can you please check it once?

I dont think so the token gets expired, have you created the token using telegram bot father bot ? If yes then its never get expired until you delete it by yourself.
the issue is related to container warmup request and being failed during startup most probably the reason is need to integrate a flask_application too in it.
